# query search and form action htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this :

```
http://www.example.com/en/search/?q=blabla
```

and I would like a pretty URL

```
http://www.example.com/en/search/blabla/
```

So my form action is :

```
<form action="search/">
<input type="text" name="q" class="input-block-level" id="exemple_search_input" autocomplete="off" required>
</form>
```

But when i edit my .htaccess i have a problem :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/search/%1/? [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ /en/?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

The Url is ok i have `http://www.example.com/en/search/blabla/` but redirect to a 404 error page.

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess in site root:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(en/search)/\?q=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [NE,L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(en/search)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?q=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You're a king ! Thanks is perfect